# pass control values window forms

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application

I have a form with 5 controls.

For textbox I am accesing like frmNote.txtNumber.Text.

When I am accessing this property directly from form frmNote then I am getting the value of textbox.

But when I created a method for example NewMethod() in different vb file and call this method from frmNote form button click event then I am not able to access frmNote.txtNumber.Text value over there inside method.

It is coming blank. Do I need to pass all control values to method from form or is there any other way around.

Comment: Please share some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because txtNumber isn't shared, you can't access it from other class. You must pass it's value to NewMethod. Code will look like this:

```
Public Sub NewMethod(text as String)
    'Use text
End Sub
```

And calling NewMethod:

```
NewMethod(txtNumber.Text)
```